# Regular Expression Pattern Error C#

Tags: asp.net

When  I have   an  Expression declared like

```
 someText = Regex.Replace(someText, @"/*.*?*/", "");
```

The Error Says
System.ArgumentException: par`"/*.*?*/"`
parsing - Nested quantifier *.

How to rewrite the code to avoid this error?

Comment: CAn you say what you want the regex to do? It doesn't make sense to give a syntatically correct expression without knowing what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like that you have this: `?*`

This basically translates to "zero or one of the previous expression zero or more times" which seems a little odd.  I'm pretty sure that's the same thing as saying "zero or more times".  Can you explain what you are trying to do in more detail?

I suspect that if you change your regex to this it will do what you want:

`(/*.*)*/`

Comment: I am  working in T4 template which generated Stored Procedure i took some line from web,it throws error

Comment: I am unclear on what you are saying.  Regardless of where it came from, your problem is what I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what is needed is a verbal description or sample of what you are trying to match.  Here is my guess of what you want.  I just added an escape for the "?" character.

```
string someText = Regex.Replace(someText, @"/*.*\?*/", "");
```

Comment: I  am working in subsonic to generate Stored Procedure,I copied some line from Web,it throws error.To list the entire code may confuse all.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're trying to parse /* */ style comments.  You may wish to try a regex like:

```
someText = Regex.Replace(someText, @"/\*.*\*/", "");
```

This ensures that your * are escaped as actual characters.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good site to test your regular expressions without much trouble:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

I hope this will help a bit.